# Powershell - When removing AC power value is not changed

Tags: laptop, powershell, power-supply, battery, powercfg

I'm trying to make a script that changes Windows power plans depending if the battery is plugged or not. I tried an infinite loop which is constantly checking on the battery status, variable "$batteryStatus" returns a 1 if it is on battery mode and a 2 for AC power mode.

The problem I have is that nothing happens, it remains in the same state. I have read that maybe I can solve this by using eventvwr.msc, but I don't really know how I could adapt this script to events.
This is the code on Powershell I have so far:

```
$equilibradoGUID = '381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e'
$bateriaGUID = '0ed875ed-d70e-4dd1-bc8e-95a18268730f'
$batteryStatus = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery).BatteryStatus

while ($True) {
    if ($batteryStatus2 -eq 2){
        Write-Output "AC"
        powercfg -setactive $equilibradoGUID
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Battery"
        powercfg -setactive $bateriaGUID
    }
}
```

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: You captured the value of BatteryStatus, once before a while loop, but never capture it again.

Comment: That was it, thanks. Adding the variable to if-else clauses solves the issue.

Comment: You need check if ac/power are/is connected or not?  Or if the battery is removed from computer? I not understand.. Sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit.

Your approach requires a restart to take effect but if you want to persist this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355331

How to change Windows 10 power settings with cmd script that does not require a restart or administrative privileges to take effect:

```
rem Change Win10 power settings w/o restart or admin privileges
@echo off
setlocal 
:minpower
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-DC 1
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-DC 2
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 3
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-AC 1
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-AC 2
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 3
exit /b

:normalpower 
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-DC 10
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-DC 29
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 30
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-AC 10
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-AC 29
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30
exit /b

:maxpower 
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-DC 1
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-DC 601
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 602
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-AC 1
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-AC 601
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 602
exit /b
```

Comment: Once again we always appreciate the contributions to the Suggested Edit queue, but please do us a small favor.  When you are changing a screen shot from a hyperlink to an inline picture, please utilize **the same URL** that the original author did.  If it is already uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com` there is no need to change the picture's URL and although we trust *you,* every time I see that the picture's URL has a different suffix I need to stop and open the original to ensure that it's the same photo. Unfortunately, there are other people who could potentially do something inappropriate.

Comment: @run Will do. Your comment should be along the lines of: "It is easier to just change the code to the picture. Why go through the trouble of creating a new image? Inline code looks like:`[![enter image description here][1]][1]` as opposed to a link:`[enter link description here][1]`

Comment: I merely wanted to explain the rationale behind my request, good sir.  I was focused on the philosophy behind it much more than the logic.